# different authentication for same site with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I have two groups that need to access the same site but use different methods for authentication.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to route them into the site.  So far I have created a web page that asks them to pick which group they are.  Now I'm stuck as what to do for the next step.

Just reading documentation, I'm thinking that if I create two directories that are symbolic links to the main site folder, I can have different authentications in the Directory section for each folder but get them to the same place.

Does that sound like it will work? Has anyone done something like this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can work.  We've done something like that for DAV access with normal access controls on /var/www/html and DAV set up for /var/www/dav which is a symlink to /var/www/html.  You can probably even do it with Location sections and Aliases (or mod_rewrite).